# How to position two divs on either side of the screen, HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

How can I position two divs on the same line on either side of the screen? I.e. one is floated left and the other floated right? When I try to do this the containing div gets cut in half.

Heres my code: http://jsfiddle.net/xy0pj0f9/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-panel-sub">
    <div class="port-name">
      <h3>Name</h3> 
    </div>
    <div class="admincp-button">
      <img src="themes/images/loginsml.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.top-panel-sub {
background-color: #bf2f1b;
color:#fff;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5%;
font-family:Trajan-Pro-Bold;
}
.port-name {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.port-name h3{
    display:block;
}
.admincp-button {
    display:block;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floated elements don't provide any stack flow so you need to override the overflow rule to tell the parent to behave as if the floated children were not floated.

Just add `overflow : hidden;` or `overflow : auto;` to the `.top-panel-sub` container.

http://jsfiddle.net/xy0pj0f9/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a clearfix. Check out this article [http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

You would just add this to your CSS

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

And a `group` class to the containing element `top-panel-sub`

Answer (score 1):

Set the width on both divs. I set the width to 50% on each of the divs in question and set the appropriate float for each (I also commented out the padding on .top-panel-sub).

```css
.top-panel-sub {
    background-color: #bf2f1b;
    color:#fff;
/*    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-left:5%;
*/
    font-family:Trajan-Pro-Bold;
}

.port-name {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:blue;
}

.admincp-button {
    display:block; 
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    background:yellow;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-panel-sub">
    <div class="port-name"><h3>Name</h3></div>
    <div class="admincp-button"><img src="themes/images/loginsml.png"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like the following:-

```
<style>

.top-panel-sub {
background-color: #bf2f1b;
color:#fff;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5%;
font-family:Trajan-Pro-Bold;
}
.port-name {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.port-name h3{
    display:block;
}
.admincp-button {
    display:block;  
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-panel-sub" style="height:50px">
    <div class="port-name" style = "float:left; width: 50%;">
      <h3>Name</h3> 
    </div>
    <div class="admincp-button"  style = "float:right; ">
      <img src="smiley.gif" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
```

you can include the in place styles separately, just for demo I have included them in tags itself.
Kindly Mark it as answer if you find it useful.